# How to skip option values and return first some

Tags: scala

I have a list of options, i want to skip none values and return the first some.

```
val list = List(None, None, None, Some(3));

list.dropWhile(!_.exists).take(1) // return 3
```

Actually it's like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
def solve(value: Int): Option[Int] = ???
list.dropWhile(!solve(_).isDefined).take(1) // returns the result of solve method
```

and I need `solve` functions to be called once for each None results, and once for the last Some result.

Comment: Maybe try flatten instead?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```scala
val list = List(None, None, None, Some(3));
list.flatten.headOption
```

And answer to your second question:

```scala
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
def solve(value: Int): Option[Int] = ???
list.toStream.flatMap(solve).headOption // or call .head if you know what you're doing
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
def solve(hand: Hand): HandValue = all.foldLeft[Option[HandValue]](None) {
  case (None, solver) => solver.solve(hand)
  case (Some(value), _) => Some(value)
} get
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def takeFirst[T](list : List[Option[T]]): Option[T] = list.find(_.isDefined).flatten
```